# Old kernel and recent CPU

Tags: 10.04, kernel, intel, multi-core

this is my question, I'd like to install Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on a laptop equipped with Intel Core i7 processor: does Lucid kernel support [the features of this cpu](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/corei7/mobile/index.htm)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phoronix have been monitoring the i7 series for a while now - for example, see [here](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_corei7_970&num=2).

The key conclusions I've taken from reading their articles is that Ubuntu runs well on such processors - BUT (and you need to read further) - the newer Sandy Bridge graphics that come with the latest chipsets are not playing very well with Ubuntu in that the performance of the integrated graphics are not on par with Windows 7.

So, look at not just the processor, but also what type is the integrated graphics chipset.

Comment: I was interested in Intel Core i7-2630QM (Sandy Bridge), you saved my from a wrong purchase, thanks.

Comment: According to Phoronix, Sandy Bridge has good support with newest drivers and kernel but support for stock Ubuntu 11.04 is broken. I'd expect support in next Ubuntu release.

Comment: Actually Sandy Bridge drivers for linux are on par or better than windows version according to Phoronix: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_snbsds_compare&num=1

Comment: You are correct - sort of - they are now better but not on the stock Ubuntu - you will need the latest mesa and other parts of the X stack.

Answer (score 2):

Processors don't change much (at least from the OS point of view), and 10.04 is not that old, so you shouldn't have any problems.